# PHPMailer will not work with XAMPP. No Errors. No Emails. Not working?

Tags: gmail, xampp, phpmailer, html-entities, contact-form

I'm currently using XAMPP and PHPMailer for a simple 'CONTACT ME' email form on my test-website. The problem is as follows. I cannot seem to be able to send out a test email to make sure if it is working. I've spent the majority of my weekend trying to find out the root of this problem but I still cannot seem to find an answer. It does not even tell me if something went wrong or not.

#### I've tried the following according to the web/ StackOverFlow/ Documentation:

- removed semicolon from php.ini for line "extension=php_openssl.dll"
- restarted XAMMP
- updated port and host values *seen below*
- DLd PHPMailer from https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer
- watched PHPAcademy's "[Build A PHP Contact Form](http://youtu.be/FtWD_ZH9lnE)" Video on Youtube

  Actually 95% of his code is his...just doesn't work for me

  Left a comment on his video. No response as of yet.

I've looked through most of the questions on this site and came up with nothing that can resolve my problem. I'm reading through quiet a few of documentation and so far. I seem to be doing the right thing. Therefore it baffles me that this simple form is not working for me.

contact.php

```
<?php
  session_start();
  require_once 'helpers/security.php';
  $errors = isset($_SESSION['errors']) ? $_SESSION['errors'] : [];
  $fields = isset($_SESSION['fields']) ? $_SESSION['fields'] : [];

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Contact Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="indexContactStyle.css">

  </head>
<body>
  <div class="contact">
  <?php if( !empty($errors)) :  ?>
    <div class="panel">  
      <ul>  <li>  <?php echo implode('</li><li>', $errors ); ?>  </li>  </ul>
    </div>
  <?php endif ?>

  <form action="contact.php" method="post">
    <label>
      Your Name * <input type="text" name="inputName" autocomplete="off" <?php echo isset($fields['name']) ? ' value= " '. e($fields['name']) .' " ' : '' ?> >
    </label>
    <label>
      Your Email * <input type="text" name="inputEmail" autocomplete="off" <?php echo isset($fields['email']) ? ' value= " '. e($fields['email']) .' " ' : '' ?> >
    </label> 
    <label>
      Your Message * <textarea name="message" rows="8"><?php echo isset($fields['message']) ? e($fields['message']) : '' ?></textarea>
    </label>       
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
    <p class="muted"> * means a required field</p>
    <button class="muted" type="button" onClick="goBack()">Back</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

<?php
  unset($_SESSION['errors']);
  unset($_SESSION['fields']);
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php

session_start();

require_once 'libs/phpMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';


$errors = []; 

print_r($_POST);
if (isset($_POST['inputName'], $_POST['inputEmail'], $_POST['message'])) {


$fields = [
    'name' => htmlentities( $_POST['inputName'] ),
    'email' => $_POST['inputEmail'],
    'message'=> $_POST['message']

];



foreach ($fields as $field => $data) {

    if( empty($data) ) {
        $errors[] = 'The ' . $field . 'field is required.';
    }

} 

if(empty($errors)) {
    $m = new PHPMailer;

    $m->isSMTP();
    $m->SMTPauth = true;
    $m->SMTDebug = true;
    $m->Host ='smtp.gmail.com';
    $m->Username = 'myEmail@gmail.com';
    $m->Password = 'myPass';
    $m->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $m->Port = 465;

    $m->isHTML(true);

    $m->Subject = 'Contact form submitted';

    $m->Body ='From: ' .$fields['name'] .  ' ( ' . $fields['email'] . ' ) <p> ' .  $fields['message'] . ' </p> ' ;

    $m->FromName = 'Contact';
    // Not entirely sure what is supposed to go here. Some ppl put their own email others the email of the sender. which one is it?
    $m->AddAddress('myEmail@gmail.com', 'myName');

    if ( $m->send() ) {
        header('Location: thanks.php');
        die();
    } else {
        $errors[] = 'Sorry could not send email. Try again later ';
    }

}


} else {
$errors[] = 'Something went HORRIBLY WRONG!!';
}


$_SESSION['errors'] = $errors;

$_SESSION['fields'] = $fields;

header('Location: contact.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things you can try:

- PHP properties and variables are case-sensitive, so `SMTPauth` should
  be `SMTPAuth`.
- `SMTPDebug` takes an integer, not a boolean, so set it to 1 or above for debug output, 0 to turn it off.
- For gmail, set `SMTPSecure` to 'tls', and `Port` to 587.
- `AddAdress` is used to add normal 'To' recipients - you call this for each person you want the message to go to (there can be more than one).
- Don't call `die()` after successful sending - your script will terminate normally without that.  - If you are generating any debug output, the redirect to your 'thanks' page will not work (you'll get a 'headers already sent' error), so whil you are debugging you might want to just echo something here instead so you know it's worked.

Much of the code looks like whoever wrote the course was working with an old version of PHPMailer.

Comment: ok. I've followed your guidelines but still nothing. Managed to echo out ErrorInfo. It says "SMTP connect() failed." Also I should've mentioned before that while trying to find out the problem I received an email from Google stating that: " We recently blocked a sign-in attempt to your Google Account". Just thought that might be related.

Comment: Well, an error message is much better than nothing! Now you need to [read this](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting). Set `$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;` to show the SMTP conversation.

Comment: Well just read thru alot of questions pertaining to this matter. Most of them answered by you actually. So even tho I'm using XAMPP as a local web server. This issue might be from my ISP? The documentation states that I could run some commands on my server. I was under the impression that XAMPP does not allow that.

Comment: XAMPP is just a package that you install on a server. There's nothing to prevent you from running other things - you just need to get to a command line. The key thing is that you need to run the diagnostic tests on the server in question - running them on localhost tells you nothing. Because (as you'll have seen), these issues are common, I've been thinking of writing a PHP-based diagnostic script to do the same thing to bundle with PHPMailer, but it's not done yet.

Comment: Was unable to find a clear way to install dnsutils. So decided to go with telnet. (btw currently on windows 7). Ran the command telnet smtp.gmail.com 587 first three lines went by fast no matter how many times I ran that line. As for the fourth line I got this 220 mx.google.com ESMTP *something diff here* - gsmtp

Comment: dnsutils is just an example of a DNS lookup tool - there are many others. Those results from telnet are encouraging - it suggests your DNS is working (or telnet wouldn't know where to connect to), and that you did manage to connect (because you got a response that looks like SMTP).

Answer (score 0):

The following code works fine for me. Try this:

```
 try 
 {
    $mail = new PHPMailer(); 

    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->Mailer = 'smtp';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; 
    $mail->Port = 465;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';


    $m->Username = 'myEmail@gmail.com';
    $m->Password = 'myPass';

    $mail->IsHTML(true); // if you are going to send HTML formatted emails
    $mail->SingleTo = true; 
    $mail->From = "test@abc.com";
    $mail->FromName = "Mailer";
    $mail->AddAddress("ankit@yopmail.com", "Ankit Chugh");   //mail to to
    $mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via mail(), basic";
    $mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email vie  wer!"; 
    $mail->MsgHTML("Your html message");

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
      echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
      echo "Message sent!";
    }
  }
  catch (phpmailerException $e) {
      echo $e->errorMessage(); //error messages from PHPMailer
  }
  catch (Exception $e) {
       echo $e->getMessage();
  }
```

Comment: No point wrapping it in a try block when you have not enabled exceptions.

Comment: php 5 support the exception handling by default.dont worry about exceptions :)

Comment: No. PHPMailer DOES NOT generate exceptions unless you pass `true` to the constructor.

Comment: i think it will generate exception if any..if not then you can add extra line to the code "$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;"  ;)

Comment: No. Wrong. It will not generate any external exceptions unless you create the PHPMailer instance with `$mail = new PHPMailer(true);`. Turning up debug output will make no differnce. I know this because I wrote PHPMailer's exception system.