# PHP send mail not working for YOPmail

Tags: php, email, html-email

I am working on the mail functionality and i have used php mail() function to send mail to different users. However, i am receiving mail on my gmail and yahoo account but not in my YOPmail account. Does anyone know the mail issue with YOPmail? What is the solution for that?

Here is my mail code:

```
    $to = 'testuser@yopmail.com';
    $from = 'admin@admin.com';
    $message = 'Test';
    $headers  = "From: $from\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "MIME-version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n";
    $send_mail = mail($to, "Testing Mail", $message, $headers);
    if($send_mail){
        echo "success";
    }
    else{
        echo "fail";
    }
```

Comment: try last answer of this post. it might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26966995/phpmailer-will-not-work-with-xampp-no-errors-no-emails-not-working

Answer (score 2):

You should not use `mail()` for serious applications, as it does not authenticate and is VERY OFTEN caught in the mail servers firewall because of that.

Instead, you should use [SMTP PHP Class](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), for example.

Comment: First try to find out that mail functionality is configured or not your server. i think in your code every thing is correct but problem is mail is not configured on your server. ask your server provider to do that.and then check your code also.

Comment: as the poster had said in the question, he receives it on SOME mail services, so the code and the configuration should be considered working.

Comment: mail sending through SMTP worked ;-) thanks :) @mariobgr